# Phantom js returns 'can't open [file name]' when trying to run example js file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Environment: Windows 7, Phantomjs version 1.8.0.

I try to run any .js file from 'examples' folder, installed Phantom.js before, added path to the PATH variable, checked version like

```
phantomjs --version
```

and it works.

But when I try to run

```
phantomjs examples/version.js
```

then get 'Can't open version.js'

I've checked file security settings and run cmd like administrator, but still the same result.

I'll appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work when you pass an absolute path to phantomjs? Does it find the file when you type `ls examples/version.js`?

Comment: Yes, it works with absolute file path. Thanks Blaise. But could you please explain the reason? And how to get it work with relative path?

Comment: If you want to use a relative path, you should first `cd` to the dir that contains the examples dir. The path is relative to the current path in Command, not to the phantomjs dir.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually I try to run qunit tests like it's shown here: https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/addons/phantomjs/README.md

Comment: Here follows example from README.md in your link: phantomjs runner.js http://localhost/qunit/test/index.html. As you can see, runner.js is executed from current directory. Please, be more careful next time.

Answer (score 7):

Was having the same trouble. Finally solved it by specifying absolute path to phatnomjs executable.

instead of:

```
phantomjs myjsfile.js
```

do:

```
/my/absolute/path/to/phantomjs/phantomjs myjsfile.js
```

I suspect setting up PATH to it will have the same effect, have not tested it though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

```
/mypath/phantomjs /mypath/myfile.js
```

It takes three days for finding this out.
Pretty wired syntax to me.

If it doesn't work then use . in front of first /

```
    ./mypath/phantomjs ./mypath/myfile.js
```

. means base dir as you set in the R studio

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was just not in the right folder, make sure of being in the exact same folder as "myfile.js"